# How can I save a property using the Props object in scala Lift?

Tags: scala, configuration-files, lift

First of all, should I use Lift Props to store specific configurations of my App? Lift documentation explains that you can use this Props to configure the enviroment (production, testing, etc etc.) but never says if you can use them for other purposes.

If there's nothing wrong in using them, how can I store these properties (save them). All the functions that I can see in Props object are getters. E.g if I have a property `myapp.myconf1`

I would like to do something like:

```
Prop.save("myapp.myconf1","value1")
```

Is this possible using Props or should I use other libs like Typesafe config or java props?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Lift Props object isn't intended to be a read/write store.  It's a repository for deployment specific config info (i.e. the settings that are different between your development/test/release environments).  The file is stored within the classpath and if you are deploying as WAR file I don't believe there would be any way to change it even if an API existed.

If all you need is to store name value pairs then java props should work fine.

Comment: Thanx Dave, I'll use javaprops